# How to create style scoping for arbitrary content with Polymer / Web Components

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, shadow-dom

I am trying and failing to create a simple web component just for style scoping purposes.

The idea is that I would define a component - say `<scoped-style>` - which `@import`s a stylesheet so that any instance of `<scoped-style>` will scope the imported stylesheet for me. I just want to separate styles within  elements and without.

So far I haven't even been able, using Polymer, to create a component which  applies `<style>` based styles to the arbitrary content any instance might contain. It appears that content which goes in `<content></content>` can only be styled using

```
:host ::content [selector] {
  /* shadowy styles */
}
```

This is extremely limiting and wrecks my `@import` plan too.

Here's the component definition so far:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="scoped-style">
    <style>
        p {
            background: red;
        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <div>
            <p>Paragraph outside content (below) which _does_ go red</p>
            <content></content>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "scoped-style"
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

And here's the usage I intend:

```
<scoped-style>
  <p>This paragraph should _also_ go red, but doesn't.</p>
</scoped-style>
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, that’s right. On the [Guide to Styling Elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/styling-elements.html) it notes:

> The distributed [element - `<p>`, in your case] remains [black] because it’s logically still in the parent page and therefore matching `scoped-style > p`. It’s simply being rendered elsewhere (over in Shadow DOM land).

Comment: Okay, thank you, Peter. Now... how do I go about what I want to do? I feel like this whole setup offers me very little utility. Do you know of a way to scope styles to arbitrary html? I looked at `scoped` polyfills but they just add a class with javascript. Rubbish.